# Firemonkey custom url scheme on OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

Trying to figure out how to handle a custom URL scheme from a FireMonkey OSX application.  So far I've managed to add details of the URL scheme to the info.plist file so when clicking on a link the app gets called.  The trouble is registering the event handler so that the actual contents of the request get passed into the app.

There are plenty of examples of doing this with iOS using a IFMXApplicationEventService but this interface doesn't seem to be available on OSX.

Does anybody know how to handle this?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm in the same situation

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this [code](https://pastebin.com/r4y6KmWz) from Victor Fedorenkov, I managed to write a COCOA URL handler in order to get the actual content of the request:

```
unit W3DConnectParamManagerImpl;

interface

uses
    Macapi.Foundation
  , Macapi.ObjCRuntime
  , Macapi.ObjectiveC
  ;

type
  TOpenURLEvent = procedure(const AURL: string) of object;

  IURLEventHandler = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{1AB197A9-FF38-442F-A942-48E2528CAC1E}']
    procedure HandleGURLEvent(Event, ReplyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor); cdecl;
  end;

  TURLEventHandler = class(TOCLocal, IURLEventHandler)
    FOpenURLEvent: TOpenURLEvent;
  public
    constructor Create(AOpenURLEvent: TOpenURLEvent);
    procedure HandleGURLEvent(Event, ReplyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor); cdecl;
  end;

  TW3DConnectParamManager = class(TInterfacedObject)
  private

    FURLEventHandler: IURLEventHandler;
    procedure OpenURLHandler(const AURL: string);

  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
  end;


implementation

uses
  // Delphi
    Macapi.Helpers
  , SysUtils
  ;

{ TW3DConnectParamManager }

// Create
//
constructor TW3DConnectParamManager.Create;
const
  kAEGetURL: Integer =
    Ord('G') shl 24 + Ord('U') shl 16 + Ord('R') shl 8 + Ord('L'); //'GURL'
  kInternetEventClass: Integer =
    Ord('G') shl 24 + Ord('U') shl 16 + Ord('R') shl 8 + Ord('L'); //'GURL'
var
  LAppleEventManager: NSAppleEventManager;
  selector: SEL;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FURLEventHandler := TURLEventHandler.Create(OpenURLHandler);

  LAppleEventManager := TNSAppleEventManager.Wrap(
      TNSAppleEventManager.OCClass.sharedAppleEventManager);
  selector := sel_registerName(PAnsiChar('HandleGURLEvent:ReplyEvent:'));

  LAppleEventManager.setEventHandler((FURLEventHandler as ILocalObject).GetObjectID, selector,
    kInternetEventClass,
    kAEGetURL);
end;

// OpenURLHandler
//
procedure TW3DConnectParamManager.OpenURLHandler(const AURL: string);
begin
  // ... use the url
end;


{ TURLEventHandler }

// Create
//
constructor TURLEventHandler.Create(AOpenURLEvent: TOpenURLEvent);
begin
  inherited Create;

  FOpenURLEvent := AOpenURLEvent;
end;

// HandleGURLEvent
//
procedure TURLEventHandler.HandleGURLEvent(Event, ReplyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor);
const
  keyDirectObject: Integer = Ord('-') shl 24 + Ord('-') shl 16 + Ord('-') shl 8 + Ord('-'); //'----'
var
  LURL: string;
begin
  LURL := NSStrToStr(Event.paramDescriptorForKeyword(keyDirectObject).stringValue);
  FOpenURLEvent(LURL);
end;


end.
```

For information, the custom URL scheme wil launch your application by adding these lines in the Info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>dontknowforwhatitisused</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>thecustomscheme</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```